# JSONDecodeError when trying to parse JSON sites

Tags: python, json

I am tyring to parse JSON sites I requested via python HTTP requests to decode them correctly in UTF-8.

When doing this I am getting this error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

This is the code I am using:

```
res = []
for url in urls:  
    req = requests.get(url)
    daten = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
    res.append(daten)
```

But when I am trying this with just one url:

```
response = requests.get(url)
textinhalt = response.content.decode()
daten = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
```

I get a valid output in correct UTF-8.

Sample of the JSON files:

```
package IRCurrpageData;
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;
no warnings 'redefine';
use JSON::XS qw();

our $data = <<'__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__';
{
   "_baseurl" : "",
   "_bilder" : {},
   "_bilderstrecken" : {},
   "_channelauswahl_canonical_url" : "1",
   "_channelauswahl_rechte_spalte_newsticker" : "1",
   "_channellayout" : "1",
   "_class" : "",
   "_gesamtbilder" : {},
   "_gesamttext" : "<textabsatz_anfang /><p> Die F<p> 
   <inline type=\"autorendaten\" /></p><textabsatz_ende />",
   "_multimediadateien" : {},
   "_resale_frei_zugaenglich" : 1,
   "_resale_treenode" : "",
   "_seitentexte" 

__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__
$data = JSON::XS->new->decode($data);
1;
}
```

What causes the error here?

Comment: There is no closing brace in the perl script, so your `rfind` finds the one near `"_multimediadateien"`.

Comment: This line  "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" essentially means you are getting "None" value there.

Comment: That was typo from me. But when its a perl script why can I load the response via ```json.loads()```?

Comment: Try  `"_baseurl" : " "` instead of ` "_baseurl" : " ` . Should be double `" "` instead of one.

Comment: If everything else works, the `"_seitentexte" 

__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__
$data = JSON::XS->new->decode($data);` part will kill the JSON parser for sure. Are you really parsing this file, or are you parsing something sent by this file? Have you tried printing `textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1]`?

Comment: @tevemadar Yes when I print it I get a valid output in UTF-8. But this just works when I request one URL at a time. But when I try to run my with serveral URLs I get the aforemntioned error.

Comment: please try this `response.content.decode('utf-8', errors="replace")`

Comment: @Hayat thanks for your answer but that didnt change anything.