# Loading multiple JSON files

Tags: python, json

So I am trying to load multiple JSON files with Python HTTP requests, but I cant figure out to do it corecctly.

Loading one JSON file with python is pretty simple:

```
response = requests.get(url)
te = response.content.decode()
da = json.loads(te[te.find("{"):te.rfind("}")+1]
```

But how can I load multiple JSON files?

I have a list of URLs and I tried to request every URL with a loop and then load every line of the result, but it seems this does not work.

This is the code I am using:

```
t = []
for url in urls:  
    re = requests.get(url)
    te = req.content.decode()
    daten = json.loads(te[te.find("{"):te.rfind("}")+1])
    t.append(daten)
```

But I am getting this error: 
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

I am pretty new with JSOn but I do understand that I cant read it line for line with a loop, becuase it destructs the JSON struture(?).

So how can I read multiple JSON files?

EDIT: Found the error.

Some links are not in correct JSON.

Comment: Highly likely that some of your urls doesn't return a well-formed JSON, or your manipulation (`te[...]`) break it. Can't say without seeing the response data.

Comment: req.content.decode() => req.text ;). Maybe for one url this is not valid JSON, print it before the load ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONDecodeError when trying to parse JSON sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799787/jsondecodeerror-when-trying-to-parse-json-sites)

Comment: @Leviathan, I am the Op of that other question but I now have a problem with JSON and not UTF-8.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With requests library, If the endpoint you are requesting returns a well formed json response, all you need to do is call the `.json()` method on the response object:

```py
t = []
for url in urls:
    re = requests.get(url)
    t.append(re.json())
```

Then, if you want to handle bad responses, wrap the code above in a `try:...except` block

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you receive correct json from any site, you didn't construct result json.
You might write something like

```
t = []
for url in urls:  
    t.append(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8'))
result = json.loads('{{"data": [{}]}}'.format(','.join(t)))
```